# Jquery Slide Show Slide effect from left to right

Tags: jquery, jquery-effects, jquery-slider

I have tried to make a slider to move left to right in a cycle, only the first div works, it moves out and everything comes to a stops.

you can see the working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chetanmani/0suk5v3t/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var delay = 3000,
        fade = 1000;
    var banners = $('.banner');
    var len = banners.length;
    var i = 0;
    setTimeout(cycle, delay);

    function cycle() {
        $(banners[i % len]).hide("slide", {
            direction: "left"
        });
        (fade, function () {
            $(banners[++i % len]).show("slide", {
                direction: "right"
            });
            (fade, function () {
                setTimeout(cycle, delay);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Thank You

Comment: what's the use of `(fade, function ()`, I think it's never called

Comment: fade is for the time span before it changes to next div. function is to run in a cycle.

Comment: Didn't you see the message " *"Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code. "* while posting this?? voting to close the question for the same reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps this is what you need: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyojimaru/0suk5v3t/4/)

first, this code of yours is never called

```
(fade, function () {
    $(banners[++i % len]).show("slide", {
        direction: "right"
    });
    (fade, function () {
        setTimeout(cycle, delay);
    });
});
```

this cause the `cycle` function will only trigger once, since you use `setTimeout`, so in your case which need to loop it over and over every `x` seconds, it's better to use `setInterval`, so change

```
setTimeout(cycle, delay);
```

to

```
setInterval(cycle, delay);
```

then for the `cycle` function, change your code to this

```
function cycle() {
    $(banners[i % len]).hide("slide", {
        direction: "left"
    });
    $(banners[++i % len]).show("slide", {
        direction: "right"
    });
}
```

and it's done, your code will be working now. But because the `.banner` is a `div` which is a `block` element, the `.banner` will be in 2 line when the 2nd `div` showed before the 1st `div` is `hidden`, so you need to add `style`

```
position: absolute;
```

to the `.banner` so it will show up in the same line

Comment: @Kyojimaru How can I move multiple DIV at a time?